# Call restful web service in iOS

Tags: web-services

I call web API from iOS, i call method POST, i cann't pass parameter in post method

Web API:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
 // POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]Person value)
{

}
```

in iOS

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9281/api/values"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

How to pass value parameter Person in POST method?

Comment: In the future you may want to look into this for something like this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/your/servlet"]];

NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"foo=bar&key=value"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

This is from this blog post: http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/making-a-http-post-request-with-nsurlconnection/